# What is the underlying reasoning behind sample.fraction or nSamp option in ranger and Rborist respectively?

Tags: r, random-forest

I am trying to determine the application of the sample.fraction parameter and the nSamp parameter in the Ranger and Rborist  R packages respectively, and what effect it can have on model training.

In Ranger, the default value is 1.  So does that mean if I am building a regression forest and my dataset has 10,000 rows, it will sample with replacement (replace = TRUE) from all 10,000 rows to build each tree.  If I then change the sample.fraction to 0.8, does that mean it will draw a random sample of 8,000 rows of the 10,000 with replacement to build the tree?  (I am assuming nSamp from Rborist package does the same thing).  If I am interpreting this correct, why would one want to alter this.  What are the effects of sampling at a fraction of 0.8 for example.

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.)
are generally off topic here. This may have sufficient statistical content (apart from how the packages work), but it's hard to say.  Please edit to clarify if you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For`R::ranger`

> In random forests, the hyperparameters mtry, min.node.size and
>   `sample.fraction` determine the degree of randomness, and should be
>   tuned (Probst, Wright, and Boulesteix 2018). [...] 
>   The `sample.fraction` parameter specifies the fraction of
>   observations to be used in each tree. Smaller fractions lead to
>   greater diversity, and thus less correlated trees which often is
>   desirable.
>   Source:[Geocomputation with R](https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/eco.html)

Decorrelating trees in a forest is supposed to reduce overfitting for instance.